# .desktop files open in txt editor

Tags: .desktop

Hey I am running Ubuntu 20.4.1 on Oracle VM.
I am having a problem that the files on /share/applications lacking icons and cannot be executed as regular software (they open in txt editor).
I try to run it as "Run Software" but it doesn't do anything.

I have tried it on Unity-Tweak-Tool